# How to block a terminal log that warns "imx2-wdt 20bc000.wdog: Unexpected close: Expect reboot!"?

Tags: linux, terminal, yocto

When I **stop** my application that runs on **Yocto (Linux)**, a message appears. When I want to write any command on the terminal, **words get mixed up** and I can not write.

The message that appears:

```sh
[21559.072859] imx2-wdt 20bc000.wdog: Unexpected close: Expect reboot!
[21564.086626] imx2-wdt 20bc000.wdog: Unexpected close: Expect reboot!
[21569.100662] imx2-wdt 20bc000.wdog: Unexpected close: Expect reboot!
[21574.114744] imx2-wdt 20bc000.wdog: Unexpected close: Expect reboot!
[21579.128754] imx2-wdt 20bc000.wdog: Unexpected close: Expect reboot!
```

**How can I block this message?**

Comment: You can use `dmesg -n 1` or `dmesg -n emerg` command to remove those messages from popping on your terminal. Refer https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html

Comment: @GauravPathak The method you suggested worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @GauravPathak But, all messages are blocked by this method. I want to block only some messages. Is there any way for this? When a USB device is plugged, it warns. But, when the message contains "Expect reboot", it must be blocked.

Comment: Try using `dmesg -n crit`, I am not sure whether it will block other messages, but I guess it will block the log messages having priority equal or lower than critical messages

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from [the linux kernel watchdog](https://github.com/samnazarko/linux-imx6/blob/1f8e1249cf0662847f2b50cb59eb45ffb33ede61/drivers/watchdog/imx2_wdt.c#L169).

A watchdog is basically a timer that periodically checks that system critical processes are running and resets the board if they stop, in your case the watchdog is trying to reboot the board but fails for some reason.

It seems that the application you're trying to kill is actually monitored by the watchdog, either because it writes to `/dev/watchdog` or in the script used to launch the application at boot (which depends on the init system you use).

So, you should either check the code of the application and the init script, or disable the watchdog in the [menu configuration options](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/IMX_REFERENCE_MANUAL.pdf) (chapter 2.11.7) before regenerating your system with yocto (not recommanded).